# import tensorflow in a Jython session?

Tags: tensorflow, jython

I am wondering whether importing Tensorflow in a jython session is feasible and if so, how shall I configure my environment to get it running.

Of course, using python, importing Tensorflow works as expected. Is Tensorflow compatible with Jython ?

```
[mata] /home/mata/mlp > python
imPython 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>>
```

whereas with Jython

```
[mata] /home/mata/mlp > jython
Jython 2.7.0 (default:9987c746f838, Apr 29 2015, 02:25:11) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.8.0_101
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
>>>
```

Update:
I tried to load the libtensorflow JAR but still, I seem to be missing something here...

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("libtensorflow-1.2.1.jar")
>>> help(tf) # OK
```

but I must be missing some obvious step to get the hello Tensorflow case work...

Answer (score 1):

No, Jython won't work with Python modules that use C/C++.

The jar you're trying to use is for the Java API (over JNI), so guess you've already seen https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_java

Comment: ...but the Java API runs incredibly slow compared to its Python counterpart. That's why I want to have the inference with Python and just retrieve the results in Java through Jython, only if it's supported. :(